# Bird Identification

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I found this bird when I came back home. I have never seen a bird like this. Also, she is not moving even if I touch her slightly.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange. For species ID questions, it is often helpful to include some information on where and when the animal was found: for birds, information on the location (i.e., country / state / province) and local environment (coastal, forested, urban, etc) would be especially helpful.

Comment: Also some indication of size.

Comment: It looks like a Bulbul to me.

Comment: Thid bird looks a young one to me, based on the type of feathers it has around the neck.

Answer (score 6):

It's a scaly breasted munia or spotted munia (*Lonchura punctulata*).
A relatevely common bird in captivity, probably escaped from someone cage? (check for rings)

Here a picture from the web:
[image]

Here you find more facts about it:

http://www.hbw.com/ibc/species/scaly-breasted-munia-lonchura-punctulata